# How do I add the upcoming events display to the home page?

Tags: calendar

When I was editing I accidentally deleted it. And now when I tried to add it back it I just have a monthly calendar instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

**Add the Events web part(For SharePoint Online)**

1. If you're not in edit mode already, click Edit at the top right of the page.
2. Hover your mouse above or below an existing web part or under the title region, click Circled plus sign used to add a modern web part to a page , and then select the Events web part.
3. Click Title and add your own title.
4. Click Edit web part  Web part edit button on the left to set options for the web part.
5. **Events list**: If there is more than one events list on the site, you can select the one you want.
6. The **Events** web part creates an empty Events list for you, with the default settings of a Calendar list.
7. **Category**: If your list has categories, you can select one by which to filter the events you show.
8. **Date range**: Select a date range by which to filter your events in the Date range drop-down list . You can choose **All upcoming events (the default)**, This week, Next two weeks, This month, or This quarter.

To read more on this check below link:

1. [Use Events web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-events-web-part-5fe4da93-5fa9-4695-b1ee-b0ae4c981909).

For **SharePoint 2013**:

1. Create a SharePoint calendar list for storing event collection.
2. Go to All event view of SharePoint calendar and add multiple entry as event with different dates.
3. Create a New view for upcoming event and modify that view.
4. Apply filter to that view for filtering only upcoming event and sort based on time.
5. Create a web part design is you want to show in your design format and fetch and show that data from upcoming event view.
6. take a only first 3 row from list while iterating.

Comment: have you tried this?